# the equivalent of php pack in nodejs? the difference of php string concat charactor '.' with concat in other language '+'?

Tags: php, node.js, md5

What's the equivalent of php pack in nodejs?
or 
What's the difference of php string concat charactor '.' with concat in other language '+'?

## in php

```
<?php
$a = 'abc';
$b = '123';
$c = pack('H*','123456');
$val = md5($a . $b . $c);
echo $val;
?>
```

#### in nodejs

```
const md5 = require('md5');
const pack = require('php-pack').pack;
let a = 'abc';
let b = '123';
let c = pack('H*','123456');
//let c = new Buffer('123456', "hex");
let val = md5(a+b+c);
console.log(val);
```

the php and node has the same output `4df955b6dc6b0e27dbab6ebbdbb0beed`

but when I change the `123456` to `abcdef`

the php echo `da8d5dffc94b9ac39e23c7099c68b5a3`

the nodejs echo `d1716795b1f658e9e8ce2cfc00456cd6`

how could this happen?

Comment: Compare the difference between `$c` and `c`. MD5 and hex representations require working with specific bytes. PHP strings are byte arrays, so it's pretty straight forward. Javascript strings are UTF-16 codepoints though, so the translation to hex likely works out to a different value.

Comment: the php `md5(pack('H*','abcdef'))` and the javascript `md5(pack('H*','abcdef'))` has the same value,so could there  be some thing happen in php `.` and nodejs `+`

Comment: did you try printing and comparing the value of `$a . $b . $c` and `a+b+c` ?